# Ubuntu 18.04: How to avoid prompt to restart services

Tags: networking, updates

I have a bunch of Ubuntu 18.04 machines in remote locations that I can only access via a 4G modem. I can access them via teamviewer or VPN SSH.

I noticed when I tried to update it when prompted from the GUI, that I lost comms to it and a local person informed me that it was waiting with a prompt as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to do these updates without having these prompts pop up and disrupting communication?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `debconf-set-selections`. Install `sudo apt-get -y install debconf-utils`.

If

```
sudo debconf-get-selections | grep libssl1.0.0:amd64
```

shows nothing do a ...

```
echo 'libssl1.0.0:amd64 libssl1.0.0/restart-services string' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

and it not prompt for this anymore. That is a permanent solution.

For a manual installation you can also do

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get install -y {package}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - is there a way to accept prompts in general, not just for this specific one?

Comment: The last one does if you make it the default.. Put the `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` somewhere it is always set (`/etc/profile` for instance) and always use `-y` with apt-get.